# Distinct is not working in procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    if(eventType=1  ) then
     set @Whereclause=CONCAT(@Whereclause," and  scheduleDate > ",@currentdate, " order by  scheduleDate " );
    end if;
     if(eventType=0  ) then
     set @Whereclause=CONCAT(@Whereclause," and  scheduleDate < ",@currentdate," order by  scheduleDate  desc " );
    end if;
     if(eventType=-1 ) then 
      set @Whereclause=CONCAT(@Whereclause," order by  scheduleDate  desc  " );
      end if;

   set @SqlQuery=  CONCAT("
select   distinct(event_schedule_id)
 from TEST_EVENT_LIST_VIEW ", @Whereclause );


set totalcountquery=@Whereclause;

  if(offsetvalue<recordlimit) then  

      set @QueryfforPagination=CONCAT(@SqlQuery," limit ",recordlimit );
     PREPARE querystatement FROM @QueryfforPagination;
     EXECUTE querystatement;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE querystatement;


    else 
       set  @QueryfforPagination=CONCAT(@SQLQuery," limit ",recordlimit," offset ",offsetvalue);
       PREPARE querystatement FROM @QueryfforPagination;
       EXECUTE querystatement;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE querystatement;

    end if;


END
```

This is my query of procedure when I try to execute this procedure with select  distinct(event_schedule_id) its showing Error

> Error Code: 3065. Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT
>   list, references column 'TEST_EVENT_LIST_VIEW.scheduleDate' which is
>   not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

When I remove distinct then its working fine please suggest me who to fix this issue.

Comment: How to fix? First you have to figure out what you want...

Answer (score 0):

While using DISTINCT and ORDER BY then we must have ORDER BY column in the SELECT list as below:

**Either**:

```
 order by  event_schedule_id desc
```

**OR**

```
set @SqlQuery=  CONCAT("
select   distinct event_schedule_id, scheduleDate
from TEST_EVENT_LIST_VIEW ", @Whereclause );

SELECT DISTINCT A FROM myTable ORDER BY B --It doesn't work
SELECT DISTINCT A FROM myTable ORDER BY A --It works
SELECT DISTINCT A, B FROM myTable ORDER BY A, B --It works
SELECT DISTINCT A, B FROM myTable ORDER BY B --It works
```

If we remove DISTINCT from above then all the statement works without any complication.